# Count availability of service in percents (GAUGE chart)

Tags: devops, prometheus, monitoring, grafana, promql

I need to count percentage of availibity of service regarding to the time. I came up with such idea:

> `(scalar(count_over_time(sum(status_metric{id="$id", status="OK"}[$__range])) / (scalar(count_over_time(sum(status_metric{id="$id", status=~".+"}[$__range])))*100`

I would like to use var [$__range] due to the fact, we could see availability of service over the time which we choose, e.g. 30d, 90d, 1y and etc.
My guess is that this query doesn't handle the problem, when we have other type of status than "OK" e.g. "Not ok:)" So it will show 100% or nothing... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap `sum()` and `count_over_time()`functions:

```
sum(count_over_time(status_metric{id="$id", status="OK"}[5m])) / sum(count_over_time(status_metric{id="$id"}[5m])) * 100
```

Otherwise [subquery mode](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) is enabled, which may return unexpected results. See [these docs on how subqueries work in general](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#subqueries).